# Gathering feedback via SMS

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect, mobileconnect

I have this scenario that I need to implement.

1. Customer visits store and makes a purchase
2. Information about this purchase is saved in Sales Cloud and journey triggers on new purchase record created
3. He receives an SMS in journey with message like:
   "Thank you for your purchase, please reply to this SMS with your feedback"
4. He replies with "I liked your service"

I need to capture that response and store it on transaction record field in Sales Cloud.
Is it doable? I'm not sure how to approach this, as it's not a standard - reply with keyword to do something scenario.

Comment: Last time I checked, Salesforce didn't have any native built-in SMS support. What tool, app, or API are you using to send the SMS out to the customer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's doable. You need a out bound SMS with a next keyword and a text response sms which will help you to write it in a DE. After you have the information in DE, use a simple update function in journey activity to update transaction record with the feedback.  Watch the below video by Eliot Harper and you will understand how it can be done. 
https://youtu.be/xAriYMogGT4

Another option is to use a salesforce ampscript to update the record directly from text response sms.